# local storage not storing data

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am building a Login Page for my web site,

**client side code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<div class="header">
    <h1>create new account</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form">
        <form action="/api/db" method="POST">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" 
                   placeholder="name" required/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" name="password" 
                id="password" placeholder="password" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">create new 
                                        account</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script>
    let name = document.querySelector('#name').value
    let password = document.querySelector('#password').value
    let form = document.querySelector('form')
    const { cookie } = document
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      localStorage.setItem('name', name)
      localStorage.setItem('password', password)
    })
</script>
```

**server code**

```
class User {
   constructor(name, password) {
     this.name = name
     this.password = password
   }
 }
 const Datastore = require('nedb')
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()
 const database = new Datastore('database.db')
 database.loadDatabase()

 app.post('/api/db', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.name
   let password = req.body.password
   database.insert(new User(name, password))
   res.redirect('/chat')
 })
```

I have a name input and password input inside a form, and when the user submit the form the script should save the name and the password in the localStorage but when I check the localstorage in the "application" tab the values of the items are "undefined"

Edit:
#oops I just realized how dumb my question was

Comment: Why is your page content inside the document head? I'd start by fixing that.

Comment: `let name = document.querySelector(...)` is executed *before*  you click the button, thus the input has no value yet ... Move that code inside the eventhandlers body.

Comment: Also there is a document.getElementById to get ID - no need for querySelector which is less specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're getting the input values before user submits the form. You need to get them exactly when the submit event is triggered. For example:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const name = form.querySelector('#name').value
  const password = form.querySelector('#password').value
  localStorage.setItem('name', name)
  localStorage.setItem('password', password)
})
```

Comment: I am sure there is a dupe for this or it can be closed as "typo-type"

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, finally found it, it's already flagged.